# UITableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath Only Called Every Other Time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am building a standard UITableView with custom tableCells. I would like the customized cell's to do something upon a touchBegan and touchEnd. I implemented these touch methods in the custom cell class and it works just fine.

Here's where the fun begins. It took a while to figure out why the table that the custom cells are in was not receiving touches. I wanted the cells to do something on a touch, but also have the table receive that touch so that it can call didSelectRow/didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. I then added [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event] to all the touch methods of the custom cell class and this got the table to receive the cell touches as well....sort of. When I run the program, the first 2-3 touches register to both the cell and the table. After that, the cell continues to register a touch each time, but the table will only register a touch *every other time* This odd behavior has me stumped. I've studied the view hierarchy concepts to see if that might be the problem, along with explored alternatives such as hitTest, but nothing stands out as an obvious solution to this. Does anyone have any theories as to why this would happen? Here is the code for the custom cell touches and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];

    if([touch view] == self.nameLabel) {
        CGFloat isRed = 151.0/255.0;
        CGFloat isGreen = 151.0/255.0;
        CGFloat isBlue = 151.0/255.0;

            self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:isRed green:isGreen blue:isBlue alpha:1.0];

    if(!self.currentlySelected) {

        NSLog(@"if(!self.currentlySelected");

        self.currentlySelected = YES;
        [self.accessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.accessoryButton.hidden = NO;

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"if(self.currentlySelected");
        self.currentlySelected = NO;
       self.accessoryButton.hidden = YES;
        [self.accessoryButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }

}
NSLog(@"Touch Began");
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];

    if([touch view] == self.nameLabel) {
        self.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:self.isRed green:self.isGreen blue:self.isBlue alpha:1.0];
    }
    NSLog(@"Touch End");
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Method didselectRow was Called");

//If it is in the Alley section
if(indexPath.section == 0) {

    //If the selected cell is the same as the last selected cell
    if([self.lastIndexPathForAlleyCells isEqual:indexPath]) {
        NSLog(@"Same");
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        AlleyTableViewCell *previousCell = (AlleyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPathForAlleyCells];
        previousCell.currentlySelected = NO;
        self.lastIndexPathForAlleyCells = nil;
        previousCell.accessoryButton.hidden = YES;
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }

    //Else the selected cell is not the last selected cell
    else {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        NSLog(@"Not the same");
        AlleyTableViewCell *previousCell = (AlleyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPathForAlleyCells];
        previousCell.currentlySelected = NO;
        previousCell.accessoryButton.hidden = YES;
    AlleyTableViewCell *cell = (AlleyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.currentlySelected = YES;
        cell.accessoryButton.hidden = NO;


    self.lastIndexPathForAlleyCells = indexPath;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

else if(indexPath.section == 1) {
    NSLog(@"Section 1 shouldn't be here");
    PlayerTableViewCell *cell = (PlayerTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.accessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:NO];
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than overriding `touchesBegan:withEvent:` you should have your custom cell override `setSelected:animated:` and `setHighlighted:animated:` as needed to handle for when they are selected/highlighted.

Let the `UITableView` handle the touches for your cells as a `UITableViewCell` has a complicated view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

As with many problems, the issue was not in the logic, but in the syntax. I had foolishly named my UITable "tableView". Which also happens to be the name of the parameter UITable that is used in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. If you notice in the code I posted above, all calls to didSelectRow() call self.tableView. Rather, they should just be calling tableView. While I can't fully explain exactly why the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method was called every other time, upon changing the parameter names for this method, everything work!

In conclusion, don't name your properties the same name as the parameter names.